# Comparing Python nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested, intersection

I have two nested lists, each nested list containing two strings e.g.:

```
list 1 [('EFG', '[3,4,5]'), ('DEF', '[2,3,4]')] and list 2 [('DEF', '[2,3,4]'), ('FGH', '[4,5,6]')]
```

I would like to compare the two lists and recover those nested lists which are identical with each other.  In this case only `('DEF','[2,3,4]')` would be returned.  The lists could get long.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

If the lists only contain string tuples, then the  easiest way to do it is using sets intersection (&):

```
>>> set([('EFG', '[3,4,5]'), ('DEF', '[2,3,4]')]) & set([('DEF', '[2,3,4]'), ('FGH', '[4,5,6]')])
set([('DEF', '[2,3,4]')])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sets to do this is a very good implementation, but for optimal performance you should use only *one* set:

```
set1 = set([('EFG', '[3,4,5]'), ('DEF', '[2,3,4]')])
matches = [x for x in [('DEF', '[2,3,4]'), ('FGH', '[4,5,6]')] if x in set1]
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is better?

Comment: Generating a set from a sequence requires iterating through it, so generating both sets requires iterating through both sequences. Additionally, performing an intersection between two sets requires iterating through one of them and performing a membership operation on the other. Therefore, turning them both into sequences and intersecting requires iterating through one sequence once, and the other sequence twice. The solution I provided converts only one of the lists, then iterates through the other directly, saving one iteration total.

Comment: If the list -> set conversions and set intersection happen in c++ rather than python, it may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Convert your lists to sets and find their intersections.

```
>>> a,b = set([('EFG', '[3,4,5]'), ('DEF', '[2,3,4]')]), set([('DEF', '[2,3,4]'), ('FGH', '[4,5,6]')])
>>> print a.intersection(b)
set([('DEF', '[2,3,4]')])
```

I don't think it will degrade much with the length of your lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **set**  the builtin support for sets

```
def get_set(list1,list2):
    s = set(list1)
    s &= set(list2)
    return s
```

And **Boom** there's your union

Answer (score 0):

```
intersection = [item for item in list1 if item in list2]
```

But only use it, if for some reason you have mutables in your lists and can’t convert to a set. Of course, it’s all depending on the size of your lists and the number of duplicates, but it could well be a factor of 10 times slower.

Comment: This is usually going to be more expensive than set-based solutions.

Comment: Yes. Seeing it myself now. It’s a factor of 10 in my tests.

Comment: However, this will work if the types contained in the list are not hashable, whereas all the set-based solutions will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2
     [i for i in list1 for v in list2 if i==v]
```