# Comparing Python nested lists and count duplicates

Tags: python, list, count, nested, duplicates

I have two nested lists with strings (`list_a` and `list_b`), details below:

```
list_a = [
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf3', 'fruit3')
]
list_b = [
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf1', 'fruit1'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf2', 'fruit2'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf3', 'fruit3'),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf3', 'fruit3')
]
```

and I would like to find identical rows from `list_b` in `list_a`, count "duplicated" rows and merge list_a with one additional column (number of occurrences) as a new list, like this below:

```
result_list = [
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf1', 'fruit1', 1),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf2', 'fruit2', 2),
('shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf3', 'fruit3', 3),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf1', 'fruit1', 3),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf2', 'fruit2', 3),
('shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf3', 'fruit3', 1),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf1', 'fruit1', 2),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf2', 'fruit2', 1),
('shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf3', 'fruit3', 3)
]
```

Is there any quick and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want a database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists   or    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029795/comparing-python-nested-lists

Comment: WEll, didn't noticed that you want frequency also.. Then those links doesn't contain what you want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict_a = {row: 0 for row in list_a}
for row in list_b:
    if row in dict_a:
        dict_a[row] += 1

result = [row + (dict_a[row],) for row in list_a]
```

On Python 2.6 use `dict((row, 0) for row in list_a)` instead of the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Works beautiful but I forgot to mention about version of my Python, it's 2.6, so I've changed it a bit. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

using `Counter()`:

```
    >>> from collections import Counter
    >>> count=Counter(list_b)
    >>> [list(x)+[count[x]] for x in list_a]

    [['shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf1', 'fruit1', 1], 
    ['shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf2', 'fruit2', 2],
    ['shop1', 'stand1', 'shelf3', 'fruit3', 3],
    ['shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf1', 'fruit1', 3],
    ['shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf2', 'fruit2', 3],
    ['shop1', 'stand2', 'shelf3', 'fruit3', 1],
    ['shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf1', 'fruit1', 2], 
    ['shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf2', 'fruit2', 1], 
    ['shop2', 'stand3', 'shelf3', 'fruit3', 3]]`
```

Comment: Works beautiful but I forgot to mention about version of my Python, it's 2.6, so I've changed it a bit. Thank You very much!

Comment: you can use `defaultdict` in pythom 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

These are not nested lists but tuples. Which is actually your saving. See 
[Most Efficient way to calculate Frequency of values in a Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172173/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-frequency-of-values-in-a-python-list)
 which should work almost right away. To get the duplicates, take `keys()` of both dictionaries, and calculate their difference.

Comment: Works beautiful from Your link. Thank You very much!